# Regression equivalent of a within-subjects t-test

Tags: regression, t-test, repeated-measures

Let's say I examine the effect of two treatments on a dependent variable $y$. Let $y_{i1}$ be the value the variable of interest of subject $i$ for treatment $1$, and $y_{i2}$ be defined analogously.

To find if one treatment was better than another, I can simply do a paired t-test.

I'm wondering if the following is the regression equivalent:

$y_{i1} - y_{i2} = \beta_0$, and simply testing for the significance of the constant.

I also suspect that the relative effectiveness of the treatments may vary with some control variable (e.g. age), and hence might want $y_{i1} - y_{i2} = \beta_0 + \beta_1X$ (where $X$ is a control variable such as age).

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. Subtracting the outcomes at both times, and testing the intercept or whether the mean statistically differs from zero is equivalent to a paired t-test. Only complaint I would have is it is difficult to say one treatment is better than the other using a paired design. Maybe if the order of treatment was random across the individuals, then just maybe. But then, one might consider thinking differently about the analysis.